# Correlation tables between irreps for f orbitals

Tags: computational-chemistry, symmetry, transition-metals, molpro

I want to define occupied orbitals in terms of [`IRREPs`](https://www.molpro.net/info/2015.1/doc/manual/node571.html) for tungsten which has f orbitals. The highest possible point group for $\ce{WF2}$ in [MOLPRO](https://www.molpro.net) is $D_{2\mathrm h}$. Unfortunately, one can't write $\Phi_{u}$ as a direct sum of IRREPS in $D_{2\mathrm h}$. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can use a table, but I'm not sure if it will give you the optimal configuration for that highly complicated triatomic. I think you'll have to try several and then pick the one that gives you the best results (for example, lowest CISD energies).

Comment: Related: https://www.molpro.net/info/2015.1/doc/manual/node165.html

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to check the correlation between $f$-type basis functions in a high-symmetry point group (say $D_{\infty h}$) and in its Abelian subgroup (say $D_{2h}$) or any other subgroup is to compare their character tables from http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/

$D_{\infty h}$
http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=1001&option=4

$D_{2h}$
http://symmetry.jacobs-university.de/cgi-bin/group.cgi?group=602&option=4

Here's how the correlation looks like for the 7 spherical $f$-type functions.

##### Correlation table

| basis functions | $D_{2h}$ | $D_{\infty h}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $z^3$ | $B_{1u}$ | $\Sigma_u^+$ |
| $xz^2$ | $B_{3u}$ | $\Pi_u$ |
| $yz^2$ | $B_{2u}$ | $\Pi_u$ |
| $y(3x^2-y^2)$ | $B_{3u}$ | $\Phi_u$ |
| $x(x^2-3y^2)$ | $B_{2u}$ | $\Phi_u$ |
| $xyz$ | $A_u$ | $\Delta_u$ |
| $z(x^2-y^2)$ | $B_{1u}$ | $\Delta_u$ |

So, you can write $\Phi_u$ as $B_{2u} \bigoplus B_{3u}$